# iOS 10 Messages App URL Preview

Tags: ios10, imessage

Is there a way to control the URL rendering on Messages App on iOS 10 with special meta tags, such as [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/) tags or [Twitter cards](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/markup) tags?

It seems like it is not based on apps installed, so I'd assume it is a white list made by Apple if we cannot control it.

Example:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple calls the metadata used for rendering web content throughout iOS "Web Markup" — this is largely based on schema.org and Open Graph. For details see the [Mark Up Web Content](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/WebContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH8-SW1) section in Apple's App Search Programming Guide.

You can validate your metadata using the [API Validation Tool](https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/) or using iMessage in iOS 10.